# d.ts file cannot "see" type declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.2

I have this structure:

```
dts/
  my-types.d.ts
lib/
  a.ts
  a.d.ts
  b.ts
  b.d.ts
```

a.ts and b.ts both reference a certain type, lets's call it `IFoo`.

Because they share `IFoo`, I want to put that declaration in a shared location, so I put `IFoo` in dts/my-types.d.ts.

Looks like this:

```
interface IFoo {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

Makes sense right?

But the problem I have is that although `IFoo` is recognized in a.ts, b.ts, and c.ts, once my declaration files are created, in

```
a.d.ts
b.d.ts
```

`IFoo` can no longer be found in those files. For example, in one of the d.ts files I have:

```
declare var _default: (depList: string[], depContainerObj: IFoo) => Promise<any>;
export = _default;
```

and `IFoo` cannot be found. Why is that? How can I fix this?

**Here is a clue!**

When I change this:

```
interface IFoo {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

to this:

```
export interface IFoo {
  [key: string]: any
}
```

now the situation is reversed - my d.ts files can see the interface, but my .ts file cannot! What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on?

Inconsistent use of module. Please use modules wherever possible aka no globals. So do `export interface IFoo {`

> my d.ts files can see the interface, but my .ts file cannot! What is going on?

Import the file containiing `IFoo` in each file that needs it e.g. a.ts:

```
import {IFoo} from "./foo";
// now use IFoo
```

## More

A lot has been said about modules
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: thanks, so it looks like I should indeed use module, not a namespace, because my module will be "external"?